# Continuous I.I.D.'s on the interval?

Tags: probability-theory

Just something I am curious about. I know of infinite families of discontinuous I.I.D's on the unit interval (certain step functions), but I am curious if there are infinite families of continuous I.I.D's on the interval. Or even just a family of two.

Comment: Sure: Represent each $x$ in $(0,1)$ as $x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{2^n}$ with $x_n\in\{0,1\}$ and, for every prime number $p$, define $X_p(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_{p^n}}{2^n}$. Then $(X_p)$ is i.i.d. and the distribution of each $X_p$ is the probability $P$ the interval $(0,1)$ is endowed with.